# Android 12 beta 5 app links not auto verifying when internal beta downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-deep-link, android-12

I have an application where the app links are correctly auto verifying as expected when I install the application package (apk file) to an Android 12 device using file manager app or using Android adb tools.

However, when I **download the internal beta version** of the app from the Google play store app, the app links are not auto verifying.

Is this a known Android beta bug or there is any workaround ? Have other developers experienced this issue within your apps ?

Just to confirm - I have setup assetlinks.json and AndroidManifest.xml so that the app links are verified automatically and they do work fine when the apk is installed using file manager or adb tools.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was caused by Google Play signing using a different certificate than the certificate used for uploading/signing the apk uploaded to the play store.

I downloaded the original application package as well as the processed/distribution application package from the app downloads section of the Google Play console.

I then compared the SHA256 signature of the app signing certificates of the two packages by using the keytool command e.g.  “keytool -printcert -jarfile 46286-1.apk”.

I noticed the SHA256 signature of the distribution apk was different from that of the originally uploaded apk. The SHA256 signature hosted in the assetlinks.json matches that of the original apk.

This explains why deep links work on the original apk file but not when installing the app from the Google play store.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! So essentially, you need to head to the Deep links section in the Play Console where it will verify if the json file contains an additional SHA256 cert used by Play itself. You also have the option to recheck verification once the change is made.